# WriteOutput doesn't produce carriage return line feed in the html source

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-9

This is being too picky, but hey...
If I use the `WriteOutput` command in cfscript, it doesn't put a carriage return/line feed in the output.

Q: Is there a `WriteOutputln()` or something like that?

Right now, I manually add `Chr(13)` & `Chr(10)` just to format the source code all pretty.

Comment: Sadly, not afaik. I have always thought there should be one, like `System.out.println` in java. Yes, it is a little lazy ... but handy given that is so common.

Comment: Here you go, go nuts: `function WriteOutputLn( Text ) { WriteOutput( Arguments.Text & Chr(10) }` :P

Comment: I just put a <br> tag in the string.  Your output is going to a browser after all.

Comment: Yeah, but the output is whether to include a JavaScript <script> tag or not.

Comment: Haha Peter :P Sure it is easy enough to write your own, but given that it is so basic, and most languages have both a `print` and `println` version built in, I have always thought it was a strange omission..

Comment: It's odd,btw, that you're ADDING whitespace to source code, when people generally take the opposite approach and minify everything before transmitting it.

Comment: *I just put a <br> tag in the string* Not if you are talking about the *source* code for readability.

Comment: I only use writeoutput for troubleshooting.  Hence I have no issues with readability.

Comment: Um.. I think you misunderstood the OP's question, which said "format the source code". So `<br>` does not really apply ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't really make sense to have a `writeOutputLn()` function in the language as most output is targeted at a browser, and CRLFs don't actually render in a browser, so what would the point be?  One could then say "OK, well put a `<br>` there instead". That makes it no use for situations *other* than when outputing mark-up. And should it be a `<br>` or a `<br/>`? or a `<br />`? That's very picky, but it just goes to show that there's no realy single equivalent that is "correct" behaviour.

That and writing a UDF is so simple - and can be finetuned to the situation it's used in - there's just no point.

I reckon that answers your question as to why it's not in the language.